# How to set JSONObject to textview

Tags: java, android

I have been trying to set textview to "name" value from the json array responds but not working but if I run this code

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        //view_member__progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        try {
            JSONObject object = new JSONObject(s);

            detail.setText(object.getString("customer"));

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I will get this result

```
{"name":"Adene Jonah","address":"Mr. John Doe 34 Tokai, Abuja. 7999.","util":"Demo Utility","minimumAmount":"500"}
```

but if I run this code below I will get nothing

```
 @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        //view_member__progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        try {
            JSONObject object = new JSONObject(s);
            JSONArray ar = new JSONArray();
            ar =object.getJSONArray("customer");


            detail.setText(ar.getString(0).);


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

this is the value of s

```
{"status":"00","message":"OK","access_token":"22071108062392","customer":{"name":"Adene Jonah","address":"Mr. John Doe
```

34 Tokai, Abuja. 7999.","util":"Demo
Utility","minimumAmount":"500"},"response_hash":"4a0d9cf3a7d63c5b0f9087931bef5540a0665add"}

Comment: You're calling object.getString("customer"), not "name".

Comment: you should post the content of s, so others don't need to guess the content of json.

Comment: there is no array in the json posted.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there is no json array inside your json content. Json array is an array inside the json content. No such array exists in your json content. To give an example, assuming the name field is inside an array. It should have looked like this then:

```
{
  "name": [
    {
      "personName": "Adene Jonah"
    },
    {
      "personName": "abc"
    }
  ],
  "address": "Mr. John Doe 34 Tokai, Abuja. 7999.",
  "util": "Demo Utility",
  "minimumAmount": "500"
}
```

A json array starts with a [ sign and actually encloses many arrays. So if we give an example on the name field, it can contain many names. But your json content is a pure json object. You can check this from sites like these. [JSON Beautifier](https://codebeautify.org/jsonviewer)